# Mocha throws timeout exceeded, yet Mongoose saves data to DB in Promise chain?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha, Mongoose and MongoDB.

My goal is simply to run a test around the creation of an account. I have the following code:

```
require( "./../../config/config" );
var mongoose = require( "mongoose" );
mongoose.connect( process.env.MONGODB_URI );

const expect = require( "expect" );
var { Account } = require( "./../../models/account" );

describe( "Account Creation", () =>
{
    it( "should successfully create an account", ( done ) =>
    {
        var data =
        {
            username: "PrestonJ",
            email: "someEmail@mail.com",
            password: "somePassword123!"
        };

        var account = new Account( data );
        account.save().then( ( result ) =>
        {
            console.log( "(temporary log)  account saved" );
            done();
        }).catch( ( e ) => done( e ) );
    });
});
```

The Mongoose promise chain executes and saves the new account to the database, but `done()` is never reached (even though it is written, and the console call above it works).

This results in the Mocha test failing, giving me:
`Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`

I have attempted to just `return` the Promise chain, but that doesn't work either. I have also tried removing `done` altogether along with returning the chain, to no avail.

It's been several hours and I've been unable to find the right practices/fixes.

Edit:
I have tried increasing the timeout for Mocha. Is the error being swallowed somehow? Is it something in my Model file?

Edit 2:
Here is the source for the Account Model:

```
var mongoose = require( "mongoose" );

const _ = require( "lodash" );
const validator = require( "validator" );
const jwt = require( "jsonwebtoken" );
const bcrypt = require( "bcryptjs" );

let Account_CollectionName = "accounts";
var Account_Schema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    username:
    {
        type: String,
        minLength: 3,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email:
    {
        type: String,
        minlength: 1,
        trim: true,
        required: false,
        unique: true,
        sparse: true,
        validate: validator.isEmail,
        message: "{VALUE} is not a valid email"
    },
    password:
    {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minLength: 5
    },
    tokens:
    [{
        access:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        token:
        {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }],
},
{
    collection: Account_CollectionName
});

Account_Schema.pre( "save", function( next )
{
    var account = this;

    if( account.isModified( "password" ) )
    {
        bcrypt.genSalt( 10, ( err, salt ) =>
        {
            bcrypt.hash( account.password, salt, ( err, hash ) =>
            {
                account.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    }
    else
        next();
});

Account_Schema.methods.toJSON = function()
{
    var account = this;
    var accountObject = account.toObject();

    return _.pick( accountObject,
        [
            "_id", "username", "email"
        ] );
};

Account_Schema.methods.generateAuthToken = function()
{
    var account = this;
    var access = "auth";
    var token = jwt.sign( { _id: account._id.toHexString(), access }, process.env.JWT_SECRET ).toString();

    account.tokens = account.tokens.concat( [{ access, token }] );

    return account.save().then( () =>
    {
        return token;
    });
};

Account_Schema.statics.findByToken = function( token )
{
    var Account = this;
    var decoded;

    try {
        decoded = jwt.verify( token, process.env.JWT_SECRET );
    }
    catch( e )
    {
        return Promise.reject();
    }

    return Account.findOne(
    {
        "_id" : decoded._id,
        "tokens.token": token,
        "tokens.access": "auth"
    });
};

Account_Schema.statics.findByCredentials = function( username, password )
{
    var Account = this;

    return Account.findOne( { username } ).then( ( account ) =>
    {
        if( ! account )
            return Promise.reject();

        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>
        {
            bcrypt.compare( password, account.password, ( err, res ) =>
            {
                if( res )
                    resolve( account );
                else
                    reject();
            });
        });
    });
};

Account_Schema.methods.removeToken = function( token )
{
    var account = this;

    return account.update(
    {
        $pull:
        {
            tokens: { token }
        }
    });
};

var Account = mongoose.model( Account_CollectionName, Account_Schema );

module.exports = { Account };
```

Comment: Send the Account source code please

Comment: I've edited the post and added the Account source code

Comment: First of all, check the DB connection is being done properly. Then, try `account.save().exec().then(...)`.

Comment: .exec() did not work, I kept getting an error for `.exec` not being a function. However, I solved my problem and posted a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. A number of things needed to be done; here's the fixed source for the `it` block:

```
it( "should successfully create an account", () =>
{
    var data =
    {
        username: "PrestonJ",
        email: "someEmail@mail.com",
        password: "somePassword123!"
    };

    let account = new Account( data );
    return account.save().then( ( result ) =>
    {
        if( result )
        {
            console.log( "Successful!" );
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        else
            return Promise.reject( "cannot save" );
    }).catch( ( e ) =>
    {
        return Promise.reject( e );
    });
});
```

1. Remove all traces of `done`/`done()`
2. `return` the `account.save().then(...)...`
3. In `then()`, use `return Promise.resolve()` instead of `done()`
4. In `catch()`, use `return Promise.reject(e)` instead of `done(e)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because mocha waited for a time period of 200ms before the completion of save action and since this action took more then 200ms, your test got failed.

Best way of handling this kind of problem is by knowing maximum amount of time your app is going to take for a response and setting that time as timeout.

You can set timeout for mocha tests just by adding a flag `timeout`

You can provide this in mocha.opts file as

```
    --timeout 50000
```

This will make your test cases wait for 50 seconds before getting timed out for any operation.

Comment: This is unlikely to be an error, saving one document takes miliseconds, 2000ms is far by enough.

Comment: I've tried increasing it a great number. I think an error is being swallowed.

Comment: can you try adding return before `account.save().then`